# Make button appears after 5 seconds forever in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin app, there is a button, which I want to make visible after 5 seconds.

I tried `Device.StartTimer`, but it make button appears after 5 seconds, and then after 5 seconds later hide it and then after 5 seconds make it appears again (forever).

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
{
    // Button

    return true;
});
```

How can I make button appears after 5 seconds, and it never disappears?

Comment: Why would setting a button visible magically negate itself when the timer triggers again though? That seems like you're inverting visibility rather than just setting it to True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is to return false so the Timer only runs once.

I.e.:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
{
    /* Make your button appears here */
    // ...
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Indeed. [As msdn says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms), "While the callback returns `true`, the timer will keep recurring."

Answer (score -1):

you can also use the **Thread.sleep(5000);** method instead in c# code.
that hold your thread for 5 seconds, then that button will shows up on screen.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is usually a bad idea since it blocks the current thread. They're already using timers to do this the correct way.

Comment: you are right, but its simple way to achieve that exact same functionality, where we are using multi threaded application, @Stavrogen, in your case you have  set visible false before load the screen, might be that help you.

Comment: That depends entirely on _where you put_ that `Thread.Sleep`. Which is something you never elaborate on.